# Disable UIButton with a specific tag

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

I want to disable a button with a specific tag, I try this code:

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:33];
[button setEnabled:FALSE];
```

but It don't work, why?

Comment: You should first check that you are actually getting the button. Add a breakpoint on `[button setEnabled:FALSE];` and check to see if `button` is not `nil`.

Comment: Check whether the button is nil before trying to disable it. Also, `NO` is generally more used than `FALSE`.

Comment: the button is not nil and I try also NO but it don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to debug and see if there is an address for the button.
Worst case, u can also try using NO, instead of FALSE.

Comment: I understand...the problem is that I have an UIImageView with the same tag and it don't work...sorry for the distraction