# How to setTitle of a UIButton with a specific tag?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

We can get a view with a specific tag using viewWithTag method, like

```
[sampleView viewWithTag:1];
```

**But how can we setTitle of a UIButton with specific tag??**

From [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612686/button-with-tag), it used the following code to set the alpha. But setTitle will not respond to viewWithTag  right?

```
UIView* view = [theViewContainingThatButton viewWithTag:tag]; 

view.alpha = 0.5;
```

I even tried [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881627/disable-uibutton-with-a-specific-tag), but no luck!!

What else I can do here?

Thanx :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIButton* aButton = (UIButton *) [theViewContainingThatButton viewWithTag:tag]; 

[aButton setTitle:@"clickeme" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Thanx :) But 'ThatButton' in 'theViewContainingThatButton' and 'aButton' are different. What I want is to set the title of 'ThatButton'. I tried, ThatButton = aButton;  But did not work. any idea!

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[theViewContainingThatButton viewWithTag:tag];
[button setTitle:@"Button Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Remember that a `UIButton` does not respond to `setTitle:`, but does respond to `setTitle:forState:`

Comment: But 'ThatButton' in 'theViewContainingThatButton' and 'Button' are different. What I want is to set the title of 'ThatButton'. I tried, ThatButton = Button;  But did not work. any idea!    ( yeah, I meant setTitle:forState and used the same :)

Comment: @S.Philip: This makes no sense to me. In the above snippet, `button` is a pointer to the `UIButton` with tag `tag`. This code will set the title of the `UIButton` with tag `tag`. I'm not sure what else you are trying to do.

Comment: thank you very much for trying to help :) Actually my problem is little more complicated,and i cannot copy all those codes here to explain. Thanx anyway :)

Comment: I'm agree, this is not work... And that is illogical :s